# Concurvity involving categorical variables (?)

Tags: regression, categorical-data, generalized-additive-model, diagnostic, concurvity

I recently learned how to test for concurvity on a GAMM I constructed, but I'm confused about how to test if 2 factors (2 categorical parametric terms), or 1 factor and a smooth term, are too closely related to be in the same model. The function `mgcv.helper::vif.gam()` was helpful, but only seems to recognize continuous variables.

Is there a way to test how individual factor variables are related to other terms in a model? The `performance::check_concurvity()` function looks promising too, but it also seems to lump all parametric variables into one term. Is concurvity the wrong word?

Comment: This was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998395/multicollinearity-of-categorical-variables